# Ride Cymbal in notation Sibelius

Tags: theory, sheet-music, drums, sibelius, lead-sheets

Hello I have this notation:

[Notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykksF.jpg)

But someone told me that is wrong notated the ride cymbal and is incorrect. And that must be notated of the G space above the staff. Can someone tell me illustrated how to put in the correct place? Or what I need to change from that two measures to accomplish that?

Thank you

Comment: You may wish to offer a better description of the notation you made *(in words)*, because when your link is broken (I can't access it), the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sibelius uses this system. It's fine.  But it's worth adding 'ride', 'crash', 'HH' etc above the first entry of each instrument.  As @MattPutnam says, there are other systems.

Don't normally use the alternative Ride and Crash positions several ledger lines above the stave.  They're just so Sibelius can offer alternative sounds.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Drum notation is notoriously unstandardized. I was taught that the ride cymbal goes on the top line like you have, and that the "G space" is for the hi hat, but I've seen those two reversed many times. I've even seen ride on the "A line" a few times, though I think that's incorrect by most standards. The safest thing to do is make a note like you have.

Drummers are very aware of these inconsistencies and are amenable to any reasonable scheme that is consistent. They're also quite good at inferring what things should be.

So in all, you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt says, there seems to be no real standardisation for drum dots. Except x means a cymbal or a hi-hat. I've always used x on the top F line for hi-hat, and ride on the leger line A above. Crash goes in the B space. But that's just me. And probably pre-Sibelius. One has to use powers of deduction, and find patterns that give clues as to what means what.